# Get name of form element

Tags: javascript

i have this simple JS for validating form, can someone tell me how to get name of field (you know, name=""), it should be where NameOfSomefield is now :S I tried with `someField.tagName` but no luck...

```
function validateForm(){
    var someField = document.forms["nameofofrm"]["someField"].value;
    if (someField==null || someField=="") {
        alert("You cannot leave blank this field: ".NameOfSomefield);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
var name = element.getAttribute("name");
```

Comment: I never understood why there's no **element.name** but there is **element.id**

Comment: @soger because `id` is generic for all DOM elements while `name` is mostly for inputs.

Comment: @soger Because `name` is intended to name members of a form. Like `document.getElementById('myGreatForm').theNameofElementOne`

Comment: `element.name` seems to work as well now — at least in the latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) approach, you may use:

```
let elementName = $('#element_id').attr('name')
```

You can find more information about jQuery selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: Nothing on internet helped me but this. Thank you.