# How can I get the First source of the video using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Unable to get the first source of the video

```
<video id="myvideo" width="800" height="400" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="">             
<source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/marimatrubhasha.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:00:00" endat="00:04:07" name="Gujarati Bhasha" description="This is Gujarati Video">            
<source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:04:07" endat="00:19:06" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">           
<source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:19:06" endat="00:34:05" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">           
<source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:34:05" endat="00:49:04" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video">               
</video>
```

```js
var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var videoSource = document.getElementsByTagName('source');
var getSource = videoSource[0].src;
console.log(getSource);
```

Comment: You should call `myvid.getElementsByTagName('source');` otherwise you will get first source on the page not in this video.

Comment: thanks jcubic. it is working but can I access the name attribute of the first source? please tell me.   var getSource = videoSource[0].name;

Comment: Try `videoSource[0].getAttribute("name")`

Comment: thanks jcubic. it is working bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myvid = document.getElementById("myvideo");
var firstSource = myvid.getElementsByTagName("source")[0]

alert(firstSource.getAttribute("name"))
alert(firstSource.src)
```

```html
<video id="myvideo" width="800" height="400" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="">
  <source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/marimatrubhasha.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:00:00" endat="00:04:07" name="Gujarati Bhasha" description="This is Gujarati Video" />
  <source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:04:07" endat="00:19:06" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video" />
  <source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:19:06" endat="00:34:05" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video" />
  <source class="active" src="http://localhost/CastingGallery/upload/2/php.mp4" id="videosource" type="video/mp4" startat="00:34:05" endat="00:49:04" name="PHP Video" description="This is PHP Video" />
</video>
```

Note that you should also close the `<source` tag with `/>`

Comment: can I access the name attribute of the first source?

Comment: use `ELEMENT.getAttribute("name")` found in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11020429/4339170