# How can I read the name of a HTML-Element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the `name` of this HTML-Element:

```
<li name="LabNr" id="c:/dmcodejs/importCSV/LabNr/test1.csv" ondblclick="getCSVContens(this);">test1.csv</li>
```

With this code:

```
function getCSVContens(Obj){
    var fileName = Obj.id;
    var importType = Obj.name; 
    alert(Obj.name);
}
```

I get that `Obj.name` is undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get name of form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020274/get-name-of-form-element)

Comment: Yes the answer is corrcet..

Answer (score 2):

Write valid HTML to start with. There is no `name` attribute for `<li>` elements.

If you want to provide arbitrary data, then you can use a `data-*` attribute.

```js
function getCSVContens(Obj){
    console.log(Obj.dataset.name);
}
```

```html
<li data-name="LabNr" id="c:/dmcodejs/importCSV/LabNr/test1.csv" ondblclick="getCSVContens(this);">test1.csv</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access data attributes in HTML5 is by using dataset API. here's how it works:

```
document.getElementById("element").dataset.media;
```

in your case, you will do this:

```
function getCSVContens(Obj){
       var fileName = Obj.dataset.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the getAttribute method

```
Obj.getAttribute("name")
```

Your script will become as below

```
function getCSVContens(Obj){

        var fileName = Obj.id;
        var importType = Obj.getAttribute("name"); 
        alert(Obj.getAttribute("name"))
    }
```